# How can I get the memory address of a value type of constant in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to get the memory address of a value type of constant in Swift. For example with the variables it looks like:

My code:

```
var value = 10
withUnsafePointer(to: &value) {
   print(" str value \(value) has address: \($0)")
}
```

Comment: There's `withUnsafePointer(to:_:)` that has first parameter not `inout`. Use it.

Comment: What do you need it for? In your example, if you have `let value = 10` there may not be an address associated with it. The compiler might factor it out and use constants instead.

Comment: I am wondering value type copied immediately after we pass it to method or after we changed it

Comment: So this is really a question about copy-on-write semantics? Then why don’t you ask _that_ question instead?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [variant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2998149-withunsafepointer) of `withUnsafePointer(to:,_:)` that accepts a non-inout argument as its first input argument.

```
let immutableValue = 1
withUnsafePointer(to: immutableValue, { pointer -> Void in
    print(pointer)
})
```

As MartinR pointed out, this pointer though is valid only for the invocation of the closure.

It is also important to note that with values known at compile time, the compiler might substitute the value in place of the variable, so the variable might not even exist in memory at runtime.

Comment: It should be emphasized that this pointer is valid only during the invocation of the closure. In fact repeated calls (in debug mode) can show different pointers.

Comment: @DimaPaliychuk I'm not 100% sure, but the documentation clearly states that's the case

Comment: this code is copying the argument, it doesn't show the address of `immutableValue` as is