# How to get reference type memory address and value type memory address in swift5?

Tags: swift

How to get reference type memory address and  value type memory address in swift 5.3?
I tried

```
/// get ValueType address
func address(of value: UnsafeRawPointer) -> Int {
    return Int(bitPattern: value)
}
```

and

```
/// get ReferenceType address
func address<T: AnyObject>(of reference: T) -> Int {
    return unsafeBitCast(reference, to: Int.self)
}
```

But, I used `let a = Struct()`, i don't know how to get if address.
I hope to get a standard answer.

```
Struct S {}
Class C {}

let s1 = S()
var s2 = S()
let c1 = C()
var c2 = C()
```

How to get them memory address？

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748491/how-can-i-get-the-memory-address-of-a-value-type-of-constant-in-swift). `let` constants do not necessarily have addresses.

Comment: Why would you need such a thing?

Comment: @matt  Sometimes, i wish to know memory address during the breakpoint debug.

Comment: Good answer but how will that help you? Structs are not uniquely identified by a memory address the way classes are. They don’t have a unique identity; they are not reference types. They are frequently being copied.

Comment: @matt Each time use the function, i get a different address.
Does this mean that I can't see the real address of the Structs in Swift? 
(You are right. Structs always being copied. I just trying to get address.)